# How to make a comboboxed silverlight control which would display in all selected items on the top?

Tags: silverlight, combobox, checkbox

I would like to ask,
how to make a comboboxed silverlight control which would display in all selected items on the top ?

Wtha what I have allready made is a combobox with checkboxes and a specific select logic.
That is working fine. But one of the business requirements stands for displaying all checked items in the main box ( I have that area in mind which is displayed when combobox is not expanded ).

Did anyone do something similiar before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this in the past by simply binding to a sorted collection e.g:

```
public ObservableCollection<SearchResultData> OrderedResults
{
 get
 {
  return new ObservableCollection<SearchResultData>(Results.OrderBy(s=>s.IsSelected));
 }
}
```

You obviously need a bool property on the underlying objects to store the selected status.